# How to efficiently parse couchbase document to custom java/kotlin types on android?

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin, couchbase-lite

I have some synced document from Sync gateway on local couchbase lite db. I need to parse this json document to my custom java type. But couchbase return me Map. I just want to know is there any way from which I could store Custom type in couchbase db while syncing from sync gateway.

Currently I am converting Map to Custom java type everytime I open the app. But this process takes some time and its affect my UI loading time.

Comment: Add some code that you have tried so that the community can help you

Comment: Hey Abhishek, I'm not sure I understand the problem.  It sounds like you are initializing a bunch of new objects when your application starts up.  Creating initializing objects from a datastore can be expensive, no matter how you do it.  Couchbase does it about as quickly as it is possible to do it.  You might, instead, consider lazy initialization, so as to amortize the initialization cost over the app lifecycle...

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike  according to your lazy initialization solution, my UI component will take some time to render because the data comes from couchbase. I searched everywhere but found that couchbase always returns a Map<String,Object>. If I do not parse this map to my custom java types (pojo classes) then it will be difficult for me to get the data from internal data structure. FYI our json is complex. Adrita Sharma I can not share the code as of now as its enterprise app. Hope you understand. Thank you guys for your response.

Comment: If your JSON is complex then it may take a while to parse it.  Try doing some actual timings.  I'll bet you will find that the time required to do the conversion from Map to custom object is pretty insignificant.  The expensive part is getting the data out of the DB and parsed.  Couchbase does that about as fast as it is possible to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a constructor (or a static initializer) to convert Map objects to your custom objects:

```
public class Pojo {
    // ...

    public Pojo() { }

    public Pojo(Map<String, Object> json) {
        String foo = (String) json.get("foo");
        this.foo = (foo != null) ? foo : DEFAULT_FOO;

        this.bar = Bar(json.get("bar"));

        // ...
    }
}
```

Unless your object are really just enormous, or there are hundreds of them, this should not take significant time.